# Chat in local area network in android

Tags: java, android

I am trying to building a LAN messenger application in android.
I searching on internet for reference project but while reading their code i am not able to understand what actually going on.
Can anyone help me or point me to some other good resources that can help me in my project will be great.
It is enough for me if some one told me key points(what are the things required for this kind of project) and just give me little push so that i can start.

Comment: Do you have an architecture in mind? Right out UDP broadcast based? Using some discovery protocol resulting in point-to-point connections? Using a local server?

Comment: so i want all user who is connected to each other from a common router and send messages to each other...yes i was thinking for udp broadcast.

Comment: Don't want any local server to play in this.

Comment: I understand your problem but this is not the right place to ask such questions. LAN messenger is old as the Internet itself and it was implemented many times by many people. Android is installed on billions of devices. I just do not believe that you cannot find a proper example. Maybe you should start with more simple project? Maybe you should look for a book covering this topic?

Answer (score 1):

An idea would be to use the open source [Alljoyn](https://allseenalliance.org/framework) framework to exchange messages on the LAN. There is also a chat example that you can download, run and examine.

More info here:
https://allseenalliance.org/framework/documentation/develop/run-sample-apps/chat